# Installing OSSEC on Ubuntu

Tags: server, ossec

After reading the [DigitalOcean's documentation on OSSEC](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-ossec-security-notifications-on-ubuntu-14-04), I decided to install `OSSEC` on a Ubuntu server 16.04: it is open source and has a good reputation. 
The above documentation is a bit outdated, though, three years old, so I wonder if it is still valid.

However, my main concern is whether to install `OSSEC` compiling from source or to take advantage of the available [Debian packages](https://updates.atomicorp.com/channels/ossec/ubuntu/pool/main/o/ossec-hids-server/) from the [download page](https://ossec.github.io/downloads.html). This is also a question asked by a user at the bottom of the DigitaOcean's tutorial: "Are there reasons for compiling from source rather than using the DEB packages OSSEC provides for Ubuntu?".

I would always prefer installing packages, nevertheless the last August someone at GitHub opened an [issue](https://github.com/ossec/ossec-hids/issues/1230) on the deb packages, which is still open.

Also I noticed that the OSSEC version of the packages corresponds to the OSSEC's development version 2.9.2, while the source is version 2.9.1.

Lastly, deb packages are divided in two types: `server` and `agent`, and I would like to choose the `local` kind of installation: which one gives me this choice? 
I suppose that installing from packages would not require to install `build-essential` and `inotify-tools` and all dependencies are satisfied.

All the tutorials I was able to find on how to install `OSSEC` on Ubuntu, even [a recent one](https://komunity.komand.com/learn/article/security-monitoring/how-to-install-and-configure-ossec-on-ubuntu-linux/), instruct to install from source.

Comment: I agree it is best to install from .deb if possible. I suggest you read up on the server and agent . With that said, IMO, I personally install OSSEC from source rather than .deb

Comment: Note OSSEC was forked, lately. Wazuh, providing with OSSEC pro-support, training, ... published their own `wazuh-agent` & `wazuh-server`. I'm still testing it out, ... would recommend you give it a look.

Comment: What is confusing is that in [the official documentation](https://ossec.github.io/docs/manual/installation/installation-package.html#deb-installation), which seems outdated, it is stated that the [Wazuh repository](http://ossec.wazuh.com/) has packages only for Precise, Trusty and Utopic but it is not true. However the OSSEC version of the Wazuh repository is 2.8.3, while the [official download page](https://updates.atomicorp.com/channels/ossec/ubuntu/pool/main/o/) has packages for 2.9.2